# Jquery Validation Plugin - Require 2 checkboxes

Tags: jquery, validation, checkbox

I have a group of 12 checkboxes, all with the same name (name="4_RepPeriods"). I am using the Jquery validation plugin and i want the user to select no more or less than two of these check boxes.

If possible I also want the other check boxes to become deactivated (unclickable) after two have been selected.

I appreciate the help! Thanks!

Comment: disabling the other checkboxes seems like a bad idea.  what if the user wants to change their selection after accidentally checking the wrong box?

Comment: Well if they unchecked one box then the rest would become enabled again. But this is an extra feature that isn't neccesary, mainly just looking for a quick and dirty way to make sure 2 and only 2 checkboxes in this group are selected and validated with jquery validation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the built-in validation rules for this:

```
4_RepPeriods: {
    minlength: 2,
    maxlength: 2
}
```

Alternatively, you can add a custom method, like this:

```
$.validator.addMethod('select2RepPeriods',function(v, e) {
   return $('[name="4_RepPeriods"]:checked').length == 2;
}, 'You must select exactly 2 rep periods');
```

Then on your validation, you can now put only this: `select2RepPeriods: true`.

Comment: Actually sorry, its not working, no matter how many checkboxes I pick it gives the error... using the custom method.

Comment: @jethomas - Updated the example to work with the current version of the validation plugin, seems the method call changed a bit.